# ActionBar color is changed when drawer opened. How to stop it?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

When Drawer open Action bar color is getting light. Below are the images.

I want same color for action bar when drawer open and drawer code.

Any suggestion???

Here is image link:

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAwys.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnPUu.png
```

below is the Code I have used recycler view here :

```
 public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

        private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
        private View containerView;
        private static String[] titles = null;
        private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

        public FragmentDrawer() {

        }

        public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
            this.drawerListener = listener;
        }

        public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
            List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


            // preparing navigation drawer items
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
                navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
                data.add(navItem);
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // drawer labels
            titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflating view layout
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

            adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            }));

            return layout;
        }


        public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
            containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
            mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                    toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
                }
            };

            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                }
            });

        }

        public static interface ClickListener {
            public void onClick(View view, int position);

            public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
        }

        static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

            private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
            private ClickListener clickListener;

            public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
                this.clickListener = clickListener;
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                            clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                    clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }


        }

        public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
            public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show your code what you have tried?

Comment: Also, please post your manifest file

Comment: Added code. Please suggest